# Call PHP functions twice removed

Tags: php, function

What I currently have are a few php files with different functions that need to be called at the start of every page.

Instead of calling each php file and the necessary functions, I'm thinking of creating a "`startup.php`" file which will have all the necessary include and call functions and simply call that one page, instead.

Would this work?

Every page, such as index.php, would call startup.php, which is, in turn, calling timeout.php, `request_timeout(),` `session_start()`, `tracker.php,` etc.

Comment: How do you intend index.html to call the php file? include() is a php function and will need to be in a file with a php extension

Comment: It will not work on a HTML file, but the general idea is functional on  any *.php, it just sounds so 1998.

Comment: That was actually a typo, I meant to say PHP. Fixed with an edit.

@jtavares, what would be a better, more up to date alternative?

Comment: @papa-nick-aint-no-joke don't get me wrong, your approach is correct, it's just that i'm so much used to frameworks that i sometimes forget the beautiful simplicity of php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good thinking/practice to group similar functions, or functions a with similar purposes... like `sessions handling`, `plain functions`, `classes`, `queries`, `admin`... in a separate files, but you can't call `php` functions from `html` file.

For example, this block of included files,  is at the top of my every page, inside `share.php` because, the functions are needed by all my pages.

```
<?php 
require_once("inc/session.php");    
require_once("inc/conn.php");   
require_once("inc/functions.php");  
require_once("inc/direct.php");
```

Comment: I fixed the typo in the original post. I meant to say PHP. The question is, can I call a function of a page that is being called twice removed?

Comment: "can I call a function of a page that is being called twice removed?" --- this phrase makes no sense

Comment: I am with zerkims on this one

Comment: ha, I'm having trouble explaining what I mean. Let's use your code as an example.

Making a "startup.php" file with that exact code you wrote in it, then calling only startup.php from index.php (thus, removing the connection to the function TWICE), would it work just as well?

Comment: What are you removing TWICE? what is the twice for? that is what I don't understand

Comment: Ignore the "twice removed", it's just an expression. I'm assuming the code WILL work, since this seems to be the only part you take issue with.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yep. no problem. if you group all the above codes inside let's say.. `all.php` you can use that file in your index page too, instead of using the four blocks of codes.